# Unable to set the UILabel of a view Controller from a different view Controller

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uilabel

I am trying to set the text label of a second view controller from the current view controller using the following code:

```
NSString *loadingString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Loading data from Instahotness....."];
self.loadingPage = [[LoadingPageViewController alloc]init];
self.loadingPage.loadingTextLabel.text = loadingString;

NSLog(@"LoadingPage text: %@",self.loadingPage.loadingTextLabel.text);
```

When I checked the console, the `NSLog` is returning me a `<null>` value for the `loadingTextLable.text`. Is there something I am doing wrong here? Note that in my `LoadingPageViewController`, I hooked up the `UILabel` called `loadingTextLabel` in my xib.

Comment: You don't init the view controller with a nib, though you say you are using one.

Comment: How are you pushing the `self.loadingPage` onto the screen?

Comment: @WTP, my understanding is that by default if I write "self.loadingPage = [[LoadingPageViewController alloc]init]", it will automatically search to load the nib file with the same name as the class? Anyways I made some updates to the query.

Comment: @WTP yeah, it will. Whether it's supposed to or not is another matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use initWithNibName to initialize LoadingPageViewController.